# How to send from Angular 5 vía POST to Spring controller multiple RequestParams

Tags: spring, angular, http, post, controller

I have this Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> create(
    @RequestParam String name,
    @RequestParam Integer startYear,
    @RequestParam Integer endYear,
    @RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile polygons,
    @RequestParam(required=false) Long reference
)
```

Is it possible to send those parameters from Angular via POST request?

I am trying this:

```
public createExperiment(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post(this.backUrl + 'puerto/create', {name:'name'}, {headers: headers})
      .map((res: any) =>
        res
      );
  }
```

But I already receive this error:

> error
>   :
>   {timestamp: 1527665099011, status: 400, error: "Bad Request", exception: "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException", message: "Required String parameter 'name' is not present", …}

Why I get this error? and if I fix that, can I then send the MultiPartFile  too?

I know I can fix this changing the controller and receiving the params via ResquestBody, but I would like to send the parameters separetely.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` is used when you have url params.

```
http.post(url, null, { headers: headers, params: new HttpParams().set('name', 'fer') })
```

This will send the name along with the url like `http://abcd.com/a/b?name=fer`

If you want to send it as a post body, then define a model in your spring code and use `@RequestBody` annotation in the spring contoller.

Look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It worked using a formData and ('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

```
  public createExperimentService(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        return this.http.post(this.backUrl + 'puerto/create', formData, {headers: headers})
          .map((res: any) =>
            res
          );
    }

  formData: FormData = new FormData();

  createExperiment() {
    this.formData.append('name', this.nameExperiment);
    this.formData.append('startYear', this.startYear);
    this.formData.append('endYear', this.endYear);
    this.formData.append('reference', this.reference);
    this.createExperimentService(this.formData).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
  //This method loads a file
    fileChange(event) {
        const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
          const file: File = fileList[0];
          this.formData.append('polygons', file, file.name);
        }
      }
```